# Pass null to non-nullable Java method from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, null

Suppose there is Java library that's declared `@NonNullApi`, but some its methods actually may consume `null` parameter.

Is there way to ignore non-nullability requirement and pass `null` there from Kotlin?

**UPD** Need to clarify: method is declared as non-nullable by 3rd party library, there's no way to change its code. The goal is to break limitation from calling side.

Obvious way is to use Reflection, but maybe Kotlin provides just syntax for that?

Comment: Annotate the parameter with `@Nullable`

Comment: Do you mean parameter declaration? This is 3rd party library, cannot change it.

Comment: What library is it? What method do you want to pass null into?

Comment: If it's a bug in the library to make this parameter non-nullable, then you could write a Java method that accepts null and passes it to the library, and call this Java method from Kotlin.

Comment: E.g. I've found such method in spring-context: MessageSource.getMessage actially can accept `@Nullable` String code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer here points out, it's better not to overcome the nullability contract of a Java function expressed with nullability annotations.

But if you really believe that those annotations are there **by mistake**, you can use the following workaround:

- Declare a helper static function in an utility Java class beside your Kotlin code. This function does not have `NonNull` annotation on those parameters where you need to pass `null` and it just forwards them to the method in question. The Java compiler doesn't prevent calling that method even when the nullability annotations do not match.
- Import that static helper function to Kotlin and call it from there.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, this hack shouldn't be used for a well-designed API. It's sad that such a simple thing requires so much code.

Comment: @AlexeyAdamovskiy well,... I think it's better this way (so much code) then the other (having a simple fix for this)... the library designer doesn't want to accept `null`-values here... that the function works with `null`-values could just be a coincidence... and if it were a mistake and `null` should be accepted, then you better contact that library designer...

Answer (score 4):

A distinct non-answer: don't do that!

That API documentation says: **do not send `null` this way**.

Even when the **implementation** today doesn't throw at you for passing in `null`, who says that isn't a bug, and that it won't be fixed in some upcoming version of that library?

In other words: write your code to match the specified API.

When the library implementation is more generous than the API specification, then rather follow the stricter rules. You should even consider to write up a but report for that library.